# I have the beginnings of a flappy bird game - the canvas fails to render/display

Tags: javascript, html, flappy-bird-clone

I have the beginnings of a flappy bird game - the canvas fails to render/display. What should be displayed is a blue sky (context defined below) and a falling bird. Instead it just shows a black screen.

The code is below: (all in one file) and the bird.png is in the root folder.

```
<body style="height: 100vh; background: #111; text-align: center;">
    <canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    

   <script>
//set up context
       context=c.getContext("2d");
//create bird
       const bird=new Image();
       bird.src="bird.png";
       //create variables
       var canvasSize=400;
       var birdSize=30;
       var birdX=0;
       var birdY=200;
       var birdDY=0;
       var score=0;
       var bestScore=0;
       var interval=30; //the speed at which the game is played
       
       
       setInterval(()=> {
           context.fillStyle="skyblue";
           context.fillRect(0,0,canvasSize,canvasSize); //Draw sky
           birdY - =birdDY -=0.5; //Gravity
           context.drawImage(bird,birdX,birdY,birdSize,birdSize);// Draw bird (multiply the birdSize by a number to adjust size)
           context.fillStyle="black";
           context.fillText('Flappy Birds',170,10); //x and y
           context.fillText('Score: ${score++}', 350,380);//Draw score       
       },interval)
       
    </script>
    
</body>
```

What is further confounding, is that it is identical (or so says my "beyondcompare" tool, to another file (code below) which works perfectly and renders the required canvas, blue sky and bird to the screen.

I changed the context.filltext to use ` instead of " or ' (for the display of the text labels) but that didn't work either. Does this matter?

**Code below (which works)**

```
 <body style="height: 100vh; background: #111; text-align: center;">
  <canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  
          
  <script>
      
    //set up context
    context = c.getContext("2d");
    //create bird
    const bird = new Image();
    bird.src = "bird.png";
    //create variables
    var canvasSize = 400;
    var birdSize=30;
    var birdX = 0;
    var birdY =200;
    var birdDY = 0;
      
    var score = 0;
    var bestScore=0;
    var interval = 30; //the speed at which the game is played
        
            
      
      setInterval(() => {
      context.fillStyle = "skyblue";
      context.fillRect(0,0,canvasSize,canvasSize); // Draw sky
      birdY -= birdDY -= 0.5; // Gravity
      context.drawImage(bird, birdX, birdY, birdSize, birdSize); // Draw bird (multiply the birdSize by a number to adjust size)
      context.fillStyle = "black";
      context.fillText(`Flappy Birds`, 170, 10); //x and y
      context.fillText(`Score: ${score++}`,350, 380); // Draw score
           }, interval)
  </script>
```

Note, I have compared them using a tool, and it shows no differences except for some spacing, which I assume doesn't matter.

Could anyone point out the error and tell me what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are places where spaces matter.

For example you have:

```
 birdY - =birdDY -=0.5; //Gravity
```

You should have seen an error something like this in your browser's dev tools console:

```
test12.html:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='
```

If you didn't, check that errors are being logged to the console.

Go through your code and the code you have copied making sure there are no other errors in the syntax.

Comment: what should it be? I've played with the spaces and there is no difference. In what other places are there mistakes. I haven't copied/pasted the code, but typed it out

Comment: that worked - but how are we meant to know!!

Comment: @A Haworth - there is also something wrong with this line - context.fillText('Score: ${score++}', 250,380);//Draw score   - - it looks identical -Any thoughts?

Comment: @A Haworth - here's a related question if you're interested :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66213195/context-filltext-score-failing-to-increment-or-display-correctly-on-the-screen

Comment: It seems to have the same problem as we already found, a spurious space. Using the dev tools in your browser and looking for the errors is highly recommended,